# Adding Functions and packages to Device managemnt Core and common

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I created a package and org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.core.log.mgt   created some functions in it.

Added my new Build of Carbon Device core as a project dependency to 
WSO2 MDM - Mobile Device Management Admin Services
precisely the Operations Class
Build the project and Deployed it.

On loading it failed with Error being 
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Any Help will be greatly apreciated. My Goal
Create functions in Carbon device Core and Common following your Design. Call the functions in my webservice

Comment: Could you able to provide more details about your modification which causes the issue.?

Comment: when I create that package, add 3 classes to it. Build the Snapshot. Added it as dependency to my mdm-admin the Build and Deployed

Comment: If you could give me a stepwise aproach to write a tiny function it would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instruction given in the below webinar and the tutorial in order to create your feature as an OSJI bundle(Carbon component) and add it to the EMM server. This is the correct and advisable approach for include new functionalities to WSO2 products.

http://wso2.com/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to create the carbon component(in here your newly created package).
- Then Create the feature accordingly.
  Then need to add created feature to the pom.xml file of the 
  product-emm p2-profile-gen.
- then makes it packs in the project target by adding a entry to the bin.xml of the product-emm

following attached tutorials gave you a better guidance and clear idea about how to create your own carbon component.
[tutorial](http://wso2.com/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components)

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/